# Troubleshooting Internal Error in the .NET Runtime

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, clr

Several weeks ago, my company laptop started having some strange problems. I could no longer launch the Microsoft Developer Web Server (via Visual Studio->Debug). I later figured out that I couldn't execute any .NET application.

In speaking with Microsoft CLR specialist after reviewing my dmp files, he said

> 1. When loaded into your process, 8 bytes at offset 0×168 into the .exe
>      files are being set to 0. This is the
>      issue that is causing the CLR to fail.
>      These bits are set correctly in the
>      file you provided to me.
> 2. C:\Windows\System32\Detoured.dll is
>      loaded into the process. This means to
>      me that the detours library is being
>      used on your machine to modify the
>      behavior of these processes.

I have also figured out that when I boot into Safe Mode, then everything works.

Also, I've figured out that if I right click on an .NET executable, and choose "Run As" and enter my currently logged in user's credentials, then the application works. It just doesn't work, if I just double click on the app.

There's lots of system event messages and Dr. Watson type errors. Here's a few that I get:

When launching MS Developer Web Server from withing Visual Studio, the Message box pop-up says:

```
WebDev.WebServer40.exe has encountered a problem and needs
to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.
```

VSHost system event log entries:

```
Event 1:
Application: MyWebSite.vshost.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error
in the .NET Runtime at IP 791A8BBD (79140000) with exit code 80131506.

Event 2:
Faulting application MyWebSite.vshost.exe, version 10.0.30319.1, 
stamp 4ba2084b, faulting module clr.dll, version 4.0.30319.1, 
stamp 4ba1d9ef, debug? 0, fault address 0x00068bbd.
```

System event log entries for running third-party apps:

```
Source: Application Popup
Description: Application popup: #APPNAME#.exe – Application Error : The 
application failed to initialize properly (0xc000007b). Click on OK to terminate 
the application.
```

Applications that I've built that uses .NET v4 Framework system event logs say:

```
Source: .NET Runtime
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the 
.NET Runtime at IP 791A8BBD (7914000) with exit code 80131506.
```

Applications that I've built that uses .NET v2 Framework system event logs say:

```
Source: .NET Runtime
Description: .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 – Fatal Execution 
Engine Error (7A097706) (80131506)
```

Here's [more details on my blog](http://jamesewelch.com/2010/09/30/troubleshooting-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime/).

How can I figure out which process is causing the problem and then fix the computer?

Comment: You have provided lots of detail, but neglected to ask a question. What is your question?

Comment: The question is how to fix the laptop so that I can run .NET applications.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moved to SuperUser

https://superuser.com/questions/194623/how-to-resolve-internal-errors-in-the-net-runtime